# Is possible render multicomponents after trigged a function in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components

For example, I created a Root Component named Index.vue, and Registred these 3 `Login, Agree and Validation`. What I'm picturing out is, after click `submit button` inside Login, the `Agree.vue` is showed and successively is happen when I click `submit button` inside Agree.

I think that I should use prop data to passing among components a `state` about each components, that way trigged a command to show the component that I want. But how I should "hide" the other components. I don't know if there a way to register the component at the moment submit form inside each `Login, Agree, ...`

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <Login />
    <Agree />
    <Validation />
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  components:{
    Login: () => import('./components/Login'),
    Agree: () => import('./components/Agree-Term')
    Validation: () => import('./components/Validation')
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi perhaps, a dynamic-component might help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50344596/rendering-multiple-components-dynamically-from-an-array

Comment: Hi, I was reading before asking here, but I trying to assimilate yet